# PHP Doctrine querying inherited classes with discriminator map

Tags: php, doctrine, doctrine-orm, dql

In this example:

http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.0/en/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#single-table

we see that

```
SELECT e FROM Entities\Employee e WHERE e.name = 'test'
```

makes this query:

```
 SELECT p0_.id AS id0, p0_.name AS name1, p0_.department AS department2,
        p0_.discr AS discr3 FROM Person p0_ WHERE (p0_.name = ?) AND p0_.discr IN ('employee')
```

Is there a way to query records only with the discriminator "Person"?

This:

```
SELECT e FROM Entities\Person e WHERE e.name = 'test'
```

returns all the records.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default the parent entity in a Inheritance Mapped Entity does not seem to use the Discriminator rules.

I got round this by creating a base class/entity.

```
/**
 * @Entity
 * @InheritanceType("SINGLE_TABLE")
 * @DiscriminatorColumn(name="discr", type="string")
 * @DiscriminatorMap({"person" = "Person", "employee" = "Employee"})
 */
class PersonBase
{
    /**
     * @Id @Column(type="integer")
     * @GeneratedValue
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @Column(type="string", length=50)
     */
    protected $name;

    // ...

}

/**
 * @Entity
 */
class Person extends PersonBase
{
}

/**
 * @Entity
 */
class Employee extends PersonBase
{
    /**
     * @Column(type="string", length=50)
     */
    private $department;

    // ...
}
```

Now Person will use discriminator rules, you need never directly reference PersonBase.